# Find out string array lengthand each string length

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, size

Consider the following array of "strings" in C:

```
const char* const animals[] =
{
    "",
    "Cat",
    "Dawg",
    "Elephant",
    "Tiger",
};
```

Is it possible to obtain:

1. The number of elements (char pointers) in the `animals` array?
2. The length of each array member, ie. size = 1 for element 0, size = 4 for element 1 and so on?

I tried using `sizeof` of course, but it doesnt seem to return anything that makes sense. I think it should be possible for the precompiler to figureout the amount of elements in the array as well as size of each element. For the latter, one could serach of `\0` character as well do define length. I wonder however why I cant get proper array size (ie. number of elements in `animals` array) when using `sizeof`?

I would appreciate all suggestions.

Edit:

1. Yes I meant preprocessor, not precompiller, sorry.
2. Why do I need this functionality?
   I am parsing incoming strings from a serial port. I need to figure out either the received string matches any string in my preconfigured table. If it does, I need the index of that item. I need the searching algorithm to be fast. Because of that, I first want to check the string size and all bytes after that, only if size matches. Because of that I thought maybe the length of each string is known at compile time.

This is my current checking function:

```
static int32_t  getStringIndex(const uint8_t* const buf, const uint32_t len)
{
    if (!len)
        return -1;

    int32_t arraySize = sizeof(animals) /  sizeof(animals[0]);
    uint32_t elementSize;

    // The algorithm 1st checks if the length matches. If yes, it compares the strings.
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        elementSize = strlen(animals[i]);

        if (elementSize == len)
        {
            if (0 == memcmp(animals[i], buf, len))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I dont use `strcmp` because `buf` doesnt have `\0` at the end.

Comment: You can use `sizeof(animals)/sizeof(*animals)` to get the number of animals (including the initial, "empty" animals which you probably shouldn't have).  You can use `strlen(animals[i])` to get the lengths of the individual animal names.

Comment: There is no such thing as a precompiler. If you mean the preprocessor then the answer is no. The preprocessor only does textual substitution, it doesn't know anything about sizes of variables. Maybe you should tell us why you need to know that. What is your use case?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You could compute the lengths of the strings in `animals` once and for all during the initialisation of the program, so you don't need to call `strlen` over and over. I don't think you can get the length of a string literal in an array (e.g. `sizeof(animals[2])` won't be the length of the strig but the size of a pointer).

Comment: Thats a good thought actually.

Comment: Another thing: if the `animals` array is really long, `getStringIndex` is inefficient, because it will take a long time to find the entries at the end of the array. Then hashing might be a good solution.

Comment: You are right. I am not sure how many animals will there be yet. I will need to think about optimlization later.

Comment: Another solution for optimisation is sorting the array and doing a binary search.

Comment: In general, I predict that there will be no more than 20 - 30 animals. Im not sure either further optimization doesnt become an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the preprocessor to build an array of structs containing the length and the pointer to the string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct animalentry
{
  int size;
  const char* const name;
};

#define ANIMAL_ENTRY(a) { sizeof a - 1, a },

const struct animalentry animals[] =
{
  ANIMAL_ENTRY("")
  ANIMAL_ENTRY("Cat")
  ANIMAL_ENTRY("Dawg")
  ANIMAL_ENTRY("Tiger")
};

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof animals / sizeof animals[0]; i++)
  {
    printf("Name = %s, length = %d\n", animals[i].name, animals[i].size);
  }  
}
```

The output will be:

```
Name = , length = 0
Name = Cat, length = 3
Name = Dawg, length = 4
Name = Tiger, length = 5
```

This should be easy to adapt to your `getStringIndex` function.

Comment: In your case, since `name` is a `const char*` and not a `const char* const`, wont it be stored in RAM instead of FLASH?

Comment: @Bremen I don't know, that's specific to your platform, but of course you can adapt this to your needs and add the second `const`.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the easiest to implement solution. Already implemented and working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. `sizeof animals / sizeof *animals` (total size in bytes divided by the size of a single element)
2. `strlen(animals[0]) + 1` (the string length **doesn't** include the `0` terminator)

Comment: Is there any way to know the size of each element in precompiler?

Comment: @Bremen `sizeof` gives a compile-time constant except when used on a variable-length array.

Comment: Thats why I was wondering either the precompiler knows how long are each members since its a const?

Comment: @Bremen I'm not sure what you mean by "precompiler". If you mean the *preprocessor*, no, but you could just use `sizeof` in the expansion of a macro. (if you have more questions, either edit your question if it's very closely related -- or ask a new question)

Comment: Yes, I meant preprocessor, sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof animals / sizeof animals[0]
```

Returns the number of elements in the array.

And also you can use `strlen()` to get length of each of the elements of the array.

From standard **§7.24.6.3**

> The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede
>   the terminating null character.

Also `sizeof` is an operator.

From standard **§6.5.3.4**

> Another use of the **`sizeof` operator** is to compute the number of
>   elements in an `array`:

```
     sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
```